# sql server returns duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in which I am fetching results from the sql server based on a list of values. Now there are two ways I can do this with:

1. execute query for one value at a time and fetch the top 1 result
2. Use a where-in clause and send multiple values.

The problem with the first approach is that it takes too much time since there are over 17000 values in the list. and The problem with the second approach is that it returns duplicates since the column I'm using for comparison is not unique. But it reduces execution time significantly.

The query is something like this:

```
'''SELECT *
FROM dbo.my_table
where AccountID IN {}
ORDER BY dummy_column DESC'''.format(values)
```

How can I remove those duplicates using the second approach? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: *define* what you mean by duplicates. Presumably they're not identical in *all* columns. If so, should you/we use the values in those non-duplicated columns to *pick* the correct "non-duplicate" row?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There is no other column we can do this with. the values I'm sending in the query are account IDs and for some internal reason the column with those values is not unique (or primary key so to speak). So there are multiple rows against one value. So when I run the query, multiple rows are returned against one value, whereas I need the latest entry in the database against that value and not all of them

Comment: the "latest entry" based on *what data*? That's what we need you to explain how we *find* the latest entry.

Comment: Based on AccountID mentioned in the query. But the thing is that AccountID column is not unique or primary key. So there may be multiple rows against one AccountID. I can use `TOP 1` in the query with first approach but that takes too long to run.

Comment: Do you have an identity column or are the rows timestamped in some way - otherwise your query is not possible,

Comment: **We** (and by we, I mean we trying to understand your question, but also SQL Server) need to understand how we take these duplicate rows and decide *which one to keep*. You're saying various different things that don't add up or make sense. The "latest entry" cannot be determined by `AccountID` since you say picking by this row returns duplicates. If you don't *have* anything in your data by which to determine the "latest entry" then you're out of luck, because you *need* data to give *a description to SQL Server* about which rows to keep.

Comment: This is very badly designed database and there is no primary key. there is timestamp but it only contains date and for some duplicate rows, the date is the same. The thing is that instead of updating the previous entry of the database when some changes occur, the person who wrote the API, stored a separate record altogether. So that makes a lot of duplicate rows with same AccountID and that too on the same date. So I can't use timestamp for that. I guess, I'm out of luck here then.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and desired results would help.  But you can do what you want with `row_number()`.  Here is a simple method that uses no subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
FROM dbo.my_table t
WHERE AccountID IN {}
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY dummy_column DESC);
```

Note:  This will not order the results in any particular way.  It is not clear that that is actually a requirement (given that the first method doesn't have any such ordering).